# monologue retrieve logs programmatically with laravel 4

Tags: logging, laravel, laravel-4, monolog

Simple question. Can i retrieve logs programmatically without inserting them into database with laravel 4? Something like: `Log::get($date/$type/etc)` or smth similar?

Answer (score 1):

Monolog does not provide an interface to read the log files neither does Laravel. However, you can use phps native [SplFileObject](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php) class. And there is also this [monolog-parser](https://github.com/pulse00/monolog-parser) library